# Why choose a random pivot in quicksort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

So choosing a pivot at random has O(n<sup>2</sup>) running at worst case but when the pivot is chosen as the average of min value and max value of the list you get a worst case O(n log n).

Of course there are the added 2*O(n) on each recursion due to finding the min and max values as opposed to the constant O(1) of the random generator has. When implementing this as the pivot you get the list sorted at the leaves of the recursion tree instead in the standard algorithm elements get sorted from the root to leaves.

When implementing instead of the pivot being a value on the list it is just a number compared to so this is not the standard quicksort but my question still applies.

Below is my poorly written pseudo code:

```
func sort(List n):
    if n.length < 2
     return n;
    min = n.minValue
    max = n.maxValue
    avg = (min+max) /2 
    List left = list of elements in n less than avg
    List right = list of elements in n greater than avg
    sort(left)
    sort(right)
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad English friends

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to rephrase the body of your question. The first paragraph is a description of how randomized and true median quicksorts work. The second paragraph seems to contain your actual question, but it is incomprehensible as is. Could you please try to clarify what you're asking in the second paragraph?

Comment: What is your question here? Is your question why we wouldn't use something like your pseudocode instead of randomized quicksort?

Comment: From the way you're wording it, it sounds like you're saying that the random pivot looks at all the values in the list, and chooses a random one of those. But the pivot is just a random position in the list, which doesn't take O(n^2) to calculate.

Comment: Your question is based on a false premiss. "When the pivot is chosen as the average of min value and max value of the list you get a worst case O(n log n)" is simply untrue. You get *average* behaviour of *O(n log n),* but you get it much more of the time. There are still degenerate cases for which the behaviour is *O(n^2).* The problem with some choices of pivot is that one of the degenerate cases is the already-sorted case, which is rather common. And there is no such thing as *'2*O(n)'*.

Comment: @EJP You don't even get average case of `O(n log n)` with the scheme proposed above.

Comment: The worst case could always be O(n²). If the key is fixed, then the degenerated case might be a list already in order or in the opposite order which could be common in some scenario (like sorting files by name/date/...). If a random pivot is used, then the probability that most selection are bad one is lower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm suffers O(n<sup>2</sup>) if you choose average of min value and max value as pivot when the list contains the following elements:

> 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, ..., 2<sup>n</sup>-1

You could find that for each pass of your algorithm, the `right` part always has only 1 element.

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. You can get the max and min in one pass of the list, so actually we add 1*O(n) for each pass. However...
2. The average of max and min doesn't guarantee O(nlog(n)), since the average of the maximum and minimum is not necessarily the median value.  If you have an already sorted list (1,10,100,1000,10000), this would actually give an O(n^2) solution, which is really bad for an already sorted list (and fairly likely to happen).
3. Choosing a random pivot is statistically likely to give you something close to the median. Take a random number from a list, 50% of the time this number is in the middle 50% of the list, meaning in the worst case it has 75% of the list to one side and 25% on the other. Obviously performance is even better when we chose closer to the true median.