# Quick Sort Algo

Tags: ruby, recursion, quicksort

My algorithm is not working as intended. When I use a data set that has a starting value greater than the last element, the method sorts the numbers in descending order rather than ascending. I am not exactly sure changing the numbers at input[0] and input.length - 1 can alter the output from ascending to reverse order. I would appreciate any insight on how to fix this. Thanks!

```
def quickSort(input) 
divide = lambda do |first, last|
  if first >= last 
    return
  end 
  mid = first
  i = 0
  while i < last do
    if input[i] < input[last]
      input[i], input[mid] = input[mid], input[i]
      mid += 1
    end 
      i += 1
  end 
  input[mid], input[last] = input[last], input[mid]
  divide.call(first, mid - 1)
  divide.call(mid + 1, last)
end 
divide.call(0, input.length - 1 )
return input
end

quickSort([24, 6, 8, 2, 35]) // causes a descending sort
quickSort([3,9,1,4,7]) // works as intended
```

Comment: You have some indentation errors here

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is quicksort (at least not the way I learned), and if you try adding more values to the first array you are sorting it will crash the program.

Take a look at this following implementation (my ruby is a bit rusty so bear with me)

```
def quickSort(input)
  return input if input.length <= 1

  i = input.length - 1
  pivot = input[rand(i)]
  input.delete(pivot)
  lesser = []
  greater = []

  input.map do |n|
    lesser.push(n) if n < pivot
    greater.push(n) if n >= pivot
  end

  sorted = []
  sorted.concat(quickSort(lesser))
  sorted.push(pivot)
  sorted.concat(quickSort(greater))
  return sorted
end

print quickSort([24, 6, 8, 2, 35, 12])
puts ""
print quickSort([3,9,1,4,7,8,10,15,2])
puts ""
```

Usually when doing quicksort you will pick a random pivot in the array and split the array into parts lesser and greater than the pivot. Then you recursively call quicksort on the lesser and greater arrays before rejoining them into a sorted array. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! However one of the constraints is that I solve it as an in-place sort.

Comment: Try taking a look at this thread, it is in python but the logic is the same: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22516/why-is-quicksort-described-as-in-place-if-the-sublists-take-up-quite-a-bit-of

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The original appears (to me) to a QuickSort using the first element as the pivot.

Comment: Ya true, but like I said "Usually when doing quicksort you will pick a random pivot in the array" but I could be wrong. Imagine the case where the array is partially sorted, picking the first value every time would result in a worse runtime. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980907/why-choose-a-random-pivot-in-quicksort